# Run Mysql Container in Docker Swarm mode?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-swarm

Is it possible to run a `mysql:8` docker container on a `docker swarm` node, without getting database errors? I already have services running on the swarm, that still connects to a local `mysql-server`.

Now when also deploying the mysql as docker container, the question is: normal docker container or also into the swarm?

I mean, when I redeploy mysql to swarm, I'd have to ensure that the old mysql container is first shut down, and then the new version is started thereafter, right?

Is it safe to run the database as follows, without ever a corrupted database due to concurrency issues of the mysql container?

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/mysql
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        order: stop-first
        failure_action: rollback
      rollback_config:
        parallelism: 0
        order: stop-first
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 10s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 60s
      
volumes:
  database:
    name: my-database
```

Comment: Im not sure if there is even a question here. The default deploy: flags are fine to deploy mysql/mariadb. My questions are, why is port 3306 being published - as a swarm service this should be part of the stack that uses it, and consequently there would be many mysql instances. And how is the database being tied to the node that has its volume - as soon as the db migrates to a different node all data will be lost.

Comment: Well the question is: is it save to run container in swarm as a single instance like above, without ever currupting the database that is shared between the instances? The mysql is not distributed over multiple stacks. And my goal is to having max 1 mysql instance active at once.